# Zumero: Cannot specify column names with a INSERT INTO command

Tags: sqlite, zumero

I have started evaluating Zumero with the Zumero Cloud Hosting option.

I have followed the 'Getting Started' guide to the dot.

Once I have created a virtual table, I have tried to insert data via a SQLite Gui Management tool, but the command failed. I have tried 'manually' with 'INSERT INTO' commands but got a error on every field that the Field doesn't exists. It took me quite a while until I figured out that I cannot insert data with the option of specifying Field Names.

So, if I want to insert data, the only option is to do so without specifying field names (and providing values for all fields, of course).

I wonder if this is normal behavior for a Zumero Virtual Table? For any SQLite Virtual table?

I have not taken it to next stage, accessing the table from within a development SDK, but it's hard to believe for me, that inserting any data through the SQLite library will not occur by the library specifying the Field name in his INSERT INTO command implementation.

Any comments is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Update: After playing a bit more I found out that specifiyng the "[FieldName]" this way will do. Thus, no FieldName and also not "FieldName" and neither [FieldName] but strictly "[FieldName]". I just wonder why?

Comment: Can you include an example of the manual SQL you'd tried? You're right, inserting into a Zumero table should require the same `insert` statements as any other table, so I'm curious to see what was failing. Also curious to know if, within the GUI tool, you'd already loaded the Zumero library, which is rather important to all of this.

Comment: 'INSERT INTO myTable ([Id], [FirstName], [LastName], [Address], [Town], [Tel]) VALUES (4, 'Any First Name', 'Any Sir Name', '4th Street', 'Any Town', '0444 444 4444');' will fail. Only 'INSERT INTO myTable ("[Id]", "[FirstName]", "[LastName]", "[Address]", "[Town]", "[Tel]") VALUES (4, 'Any First Name', 'Any Sir Name', '4th Street', 'Any Town', '0444 444 4444');' will do.

Comment: And of course, within the GUI tool zumero.dll extension has been successfully loaded.

Comment: How/where did you create the table? It sounds like the brackets are actually part of the field names, which wouldn't happen using the SQLite shell -- unless they were actually specified during table creation.

Comment: I have created two different databases each of them with a Zumero virtual table. One was done with the GUI and the other with the SQLite  shell. Both yielding the exact very some results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've uncovered a limitation of Zumero's parser. The short answer is, don't use MSSQL-style square brackets to delimit fields when talking to Zumero cloud DBs, instead use standard-SQL-style double quotes.

So:

```
create virtual table foo using zumero ("Id", "FirstName", "LastName", "Address");
```

instead of:

```
create virtual table foo using zumero ([Id], [FirstName], [LastName], [Address]);
```

Using the first example, you can then insert via:

```
insert into foo (FirstName, LastName) values ('Fred', 'Flintstone');
```

or

```
insert into foo ("FirstName", "LastName") values ('Barney', 'Rubble');
```

or any combination thereof.

Comment: Thanks! Can we expect then that this will be added to your bug / todo repository? Can we reckon then it will be addressed in further releases?

Comment: I've logged the bug, but I don't have a timeframe for potential fixes. The limitation *will* be added to the web documentation in the next day or so, however, so thanks for that, and sorry for the inconvenience.